# Swift: closure as parameter reports error

Tags: swift

just writing a simple swift app and this error came up.

```
protocol FormDelegate {
    func formDidFinish(form: Form)
}

class Form {
    var delegate: FormDelegate?

    func testClosure(sender: () -> Void) {
    }
}

let form = Form()
form.testClosure {
//      let removeCommentToGetRidOfError = true
    form.delegate?.formDidFinish(form) // error: Cannot convert the expression's type '() -> () -> $T2' to type '()'
}
```

but when i insert the let statement, everything works. Any clue what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that closures have auto return, when there are no explicit return. In this case the return value is `Void?` as there is optional chaining involved. You can fix this by returning as last statement:

```
form.testClosure {
    form.delegate?.formDidFinish(form)
    return
}
```

or make testClosure return `Void?`

```
class Form {
    var delegate: FormDelegate?

    func testClosure(sender: () -> Void?) {
    }
}
```

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. now even the error message make sense. thanks :)

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. How does `Void` differ from `Void?`, from a conceptual standpoint? Does it?

Comment: `Void?` is optional, just like `Int?` etc... It can be `nil (None)` or `Void (Some)`. It main use is in optional chaining method calls to tell whether methods returning `Void` where ever called.

Answer (score 1):

If the closure has one expression swift tries to return that expreeions result. There is great blog post about this feature ( or bug? ) in swift. 
[link](http://ashfurrow.com/blog/expression-interpretation-problem-with-swift-closures)